# File locking in Linux using C program

Tags: filelock

I want to create one file from c program and i want use bit long time in my c binary. But i want create file in such way that until my c program finish processing file created and unlock it nobody(may using vim or any other editor) can able to open and read file contents.

Please help me on this thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you [STFW](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=linux+mandatory+locking)?

Comment: You [kind of can](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl), but you [**SHOULDN'T**](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt).

Answer (score 6):

You can define a mandatory file lock on Unix, for this purpose.
However, it's necessary to (re-)mount file system, so that it honors mandatory locks.

1 For example to remount the root fs, use (as root):

```
mount -oremount,mand /
```

2 Now, let's create our secret file:

```
echo "big secret" > locked_file
```

3 We need to set-group-id, and disable group execution privileges on the file:

```
chmod g+s,g-x locked_file
```

And our C code to lock that file:
(The code will lock the file, and keep it locked for a while, you can try another terminal to read it, the read will be delayed until lock is released)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

struct flock fl;
int fd;

fl.l_type   = F_WRLCK;  /* read/write lock */
fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET; /* beginning of file */
fl.l_start  = 0;        /* offset from l_whence */
fl.l_len    = 0;        /* length, 0 = to EOF */
fl.l_pid    = getpid(); /* PID */

fd = open("locked_file", O_RDWR | O_EXCL); /* not 100% sure if O_EXCL needed */

fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl); /* set lock */

usleep(10000000);

printf("\n release lock \n");

fl.l_type   = F_UNLCK;
fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl); /* unset lock */

}
```

More info at 
http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt

Answer (score 1):

Files can be locked by using flock(). Its syntax is

```
#include <sys/file.h>
#define   LOCK_SH   1    /* shared lock */
#define   LOCK_EX   2    /* exclusive lock */
#define   LOCK_NB   4    /* don't block when locking */
#define   LOCK_UN   8    /* unlock */

int flock(int fd, int operation);
```

First file is opened using fopen() or open(). Then this opened file is locked using flock() as given below

```
int fd = open("test.txt","r");
int lock = flock(fd, LOCK_SH);  // Lock the file . . .
// . . . .
// Locked file in use 
// . . . .
int release = flock(fd, LOCK_UN);  // Unlock the file . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the first answer (short and sweet) but it does not work, as-is, with gcc on CentOS-7. This little hack satisfies my needs for use with a little app involving procmail (Note: if you are updating the data file contents then be sure to call fflush before releasing the lock. Otherwise, skip the lock release and just call fclose since it appears that the lock is removed at that time)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
//
#define LOCK_SH 1   // shared lock
#define LOCK_EX 2   // exclusive lock
#define LOCK_NB 4   // don't block when locking
#define LOCK_UN 8   // unlock
extern int errno;   // this is located elsewhere
//
void debug(int rc){
    if ((rc>0)||(errno>0)){
    printf("rc: %d err: %d\n", rc, errno);
        errno = 0;  // clear for next time
    }
}   
//
void main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int rc;
    //
    printf("fopen\n");
    fp = fopen("flock_demo.dat","r+");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("err: %d\n", errno);
    perror("-e-cannot open file");
    exit(2);
    }
    printf("flock\n");
    rc = flock( fileno(fp), LOCK_EX );
    debug(rc);
    printf("now run this program on another session\n");
    printf("then hit <enter> to continue");
    getchar();
    printf("\n");
    printf("funlock\n");
    rc = flock( fileno(fp), LOCK_UN );
    debug(rc);
    printf("fclose\n");
    rc = fclose(fp);
    debug(rc);
}
```